# DATABASE RELATED ERROR" SUCH AS SQLSTATE[HY000][2002]

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, database, database-connection

Why do some Magento 2 installations encounter database-related errors, such as "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused" or "Table 'magento.x' doesn't exist"?**strong text**

Answer (score 2):

You probably have wrong credential in your env.php for the database. Try to connect first to your database without magento.